# ERROR: relation "Table" does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am working on a project with Django 1.7 and PostgreSQL. When I access database tables through the Django admin it's working fine, but when I try to access those tables from the PostgreSQL console some are working fine, but some throw an error.

For example, the following query works.

```
select * from post_my;
id | owner_id | content
---+----------+---------
(0 rows)
```

However, the following query does not:

```
select * from Doctors_city;
```

> ERROR: relation "doctors_city" does not exist
>
> LINE 1: select * from Doctors_city;

I tried to search on google and stack, but not getting any use full solution.

Comment: What are the queries/commands you run on the postgres console that give you the error?

Comment: select * from post_my;                                                                                   id | owner_id | content 
----+----------+---------
(0 rows) it's working fine but   select * from Doctors_city;                     ERROR:  relation "doctors_city" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Doctors_city;

Comment: All identifiers that are not double-quoted are folded to lowercase in PostgreSQL (cf [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/1644198)) so you need to do: `select * from "Doctors_city"; `